# Returning the table using django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I wrote a function that generates an array of strings and an array of integers in views.py.

```
List=["car", "dog", "cat"]
Array = [1,4,7]
```

How can I return these values in a form of table on web page using Django? Is it possible to iterate these arrays in template?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Read official docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for

You can do a for loop in template like:

```
<ul>
    {% for athlete in athlete_list %}
        <li>{{ athlete.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```